# My Icecast Stream is not playing in my android application

Tags: java, android, audio-streaming, icecast

I am trying to write an android app that streams from an icecast server when you click play.  This is for a radio station that I help out in my area, and they need to get out in the community, and be able to advertise.  I have written some android apps before, but my experience with this is limited.

There are no errors in the code according to android studio, and the app does everything the way it is supposed to except play the stream.  I have tested the stream on my browser, and it is up and running.

```
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import java.io.IOException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button b_play;

MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

boolean prepared = false;
boolean started = false;


String stream = "<server address>";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    b_play = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b_play);
    b_play.setEnabled(false);
    b_play.setText("LOADING...");


    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

    new PlayerTask().execute(stream);

    b_play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()  {
        @Override
        public void  onClick(View view)  {
            if(started) {
                started = false;
                mediaPlayer.pause();
                b_play.setText("PLAY");
            }else{
                started = true;
                mediaPlayer.start();
                b_play.setText("PAUSE");
            }
        }
    });
}


class PlayerTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean>{


    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... strings) {

        try {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(strings[0]);
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
            prepared = true;
        }  catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return prepared;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean aboolean) {
        super.onPostExecute(aboolean);
        mediaPlayer.start();
        b_play.setEnabled(true);
        b_play.setText("PLAY");
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if(started) {
        mediaPlayer.pause();
    }
}
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if(started) {
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if(prepared){
        mediaPlayer.release();
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Icecast has delay picking up Android apps. If you have 32k streaming it can take up to 40 seconds for the stream to load. 64k can take awhile also.
Shoutcast servers pick up almost instantly.
https://androidaudio.info/android-audio-buffering-issues-with-32k-acc-icecast-server/